# How to draw something like a spiral in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw something like a spiral which is shown in the picture below. The most important thing for me is this kind of spiral, because two rings are easy to draw. Could you help me with this?     [image]

Comment: `\draw plot[domain=...:...]  (\angle:<formula for distance>);` ? what you try so far?

Comment: Questions like "Draw this for me" are often deemed too broad and will have a lower answer rate. Show what you have so far in form of a MWE, a compilable code that illustrates the question, and you increase the chances of answers considerably. Then the illustration you have given can be used to show what is missing in your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] circle (1) circle (3);
  \draw[domain=0:725,samples=50,smooth,line width=3mm,gray!50]
    plot (\x:{2+0.5*sin(0.5*(\x-45))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the formula `2+0.5*sin(0.5*(\x-45))` you can adjust the following values: The value `2` is the distance from the center where the braid intersects with itself. The first `0.5` is the maximal distance that the braid moves away from the circle with radius `2`; here it oscillates between 2-0.5=1.5 and 2+0.5=2.5. Finally, the number `45` is the angle at which the braid intersects with itself. The width of the braid is currently 3mm, determined by the option `line width=3mm`.

[image]